# Slower wireless speed in Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) on Asus USB-N13

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Asus USB-N13 which I use for wireless internet on my desktop. The download speed I get on Windows 7 (dual-boot) is 15.22 Mbps. On Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) I can only get 1.09 Mbps. I asked a question about this on the Ubuntu forums as well, but I did not get an answer. Here is the output from

```
lsmod | grep rt
```

which gives me,

```
parport_pc             32866  0 
rtl8192cu             103297  0 
rtl8192c_common        75767  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi               111202  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              506816  3 rtl8192cu,rtl8192c_common,rtlwifi
cfg80211              205544  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
```

I installed the drivers from Realtek (my chipset is Realtek, not Ralink) but that did not work.

Comment: I have had the same issue...  Mine seems to be intermittently bad though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for this. I combined instructions from different websites to get this (from https://askubuntu.com/questions/168627/connecting-asus-usb-n13-wireless-adapter and http://act28.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/how-to-get-asus-usb-n13-adapter-working.html).

First start by downloading the drivers the drivers from Realtek from this website - http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true

Note: Make sure that you scroll down and download the driver that matches the output from your lsmod (eg: rtl8192cu). I am also going to copy and paste some of the stuff straight from the other answers.

Next get the Linux headers necessary to build the drivers. Type/paste in the terminal, entering your password when asked:

> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`

Then, we'll install the software tools necessary to build the drivers. Type/paste:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

Now, let's build the drivers!

Paste the below:

> cd ~/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.3_4369.20120622

Then type/paste:

> sudo bash install.sh

You will see lines of text scroll by, pause, and scroll by again, as the driver is built and installed. You will know it's done when the prompt returns, preceded by this message:

> install -p -m 644 8192cu.ko  /lib/modules/3.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
>   /sbin/depmod -a 3.2.0-27-generic
>
> The Setup Script is completed !

Next you need to open the following files and modify them:

> sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/network_drivers.conf

Once it is opened add the following lines to the file and save it:

> install rt3070sta /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rt3070sta $CMDLINE_OPTS; /bin/echo "0b05 1784" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2870/new_id

Then modify this file as well using the command:

> sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/network_drivers.rules

and to this add:

> ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", ATTR{idProduct}=="1784", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -qba rt3070sta"

Now just save the file and close the terminal window and restart. It should work on the first restart at full speed. If adapter is not recognized at the first bootup, then unplug and plug it back in for it to work(you will only have to do this once on the first bootup and then it should be auto recognized on every other restart after the first one).